# creating multiple qr code in different page

Tags: php, qr-code

I have problem how to print one qr code in one page. now my output have three qr code in one page of pdf. so, can anyone point me the problem? Once solved it I'll move forward. Thanks!

```
require_once("qrcode/fpdf17/fpdf.php");
require_once("qrcode/phpqrcode/qrlib.php");

 
$pdf = new FPDF('P','mm','A4');

$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->Image("download.php?file=qrcode/gbrqrcode/QRQ1340712030.png", 10, 30, 100, 0, "png");  //first

$pdf->Image("download.php?file=qrcode/gbrqrcode/QRQ1995785355.png", 40, 30, 100, 0, "png");   //second

$pdf->Image("download.php?file=qrcode/gbrqrcode/QRQ124998194.png", 100, 30, 100, 0, "png");     //third



$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: I did not understand your problem, can you explain better pls?

Comment: Not used it myself, but does `$pdf->AddPage();` need to be called between each time you add an image?

Comment: If you need you qrCode in each page you need to use `$pdf->AddPage();` before every new content as Nigel said.

Comment: okay.. thank you